# No source code is available for type java.security.InvalidParameterException

Tags: java, gwt

I have one method where I used `InvalidParameterException()` class to throw the invalid parameter exception. I am used this class from `GWT` client side code. When I ran this method then I got this exception

> No source code is available for type
>   java.security.InvalidParameterException; did you forget to inherit a
>   required module?

I know why this exception is coming because I did not used any inherits module for that. But my question is that what module I used for this to run my program?

I used `InvalidParameterException` from this below method

```
public static List<Coordinate> getIntersectionPoints(Shape shape1, Shape shape2) {
    if ((shape1 != null) && (shape2 != null)) {
      if ((shape1 instanceof Line) && (shape2 instanceof Line)) {
        return getIntersectionPoints((Line)shape1, (Line)shape2);
      }
    }

    throw new InvalidParameterException();
  }
```

If I am not right then what should I do to solve this issue?

Comment: It looks like 'java.security.InvalidParameterException' is not part of the JRE Emulation in GWT.  http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html

Comment: @ElHoss That means InvalidParameterException will not support from GWT client side?

Comment: Regarding the JRE Emulation doc, I would say yes.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any specific reason for using InvalidParameterException? From the code sample, it seems that if either shape is null, you want to throw exception. I think [IllegalArgumentException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) is best suited for such parameter sanity checks.